# What's this java pattern called?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I'm wondering what the following pattern is called, if it has a name at all.

**Purpose**

Store data that is associated with an object (`MyObject`), but that is private to an implementation of an interface that deals with that object. Clients of the object have no business looking at this data.

**Alternatives**

Some alternatives are

1. a `WeakHashMap<MyObject, FooApiMyObjectAttachment>` maintained in the implementation of the interface,
2. using subclassing and factories everywhere the value is created, so that the extra data can be stored in the subclass or
3. using subclassing and accepting both `MyObject` **and** subclasses in the API.

**Code example**

```
public interface MyApi {
  void doSomething(MyObject x);
}

public class MyObject {
  public interface Attachment {} // empty interface, type bound only
  private Attachment attachment;
  public void setAttachment(Attachment attachment) {
    this.attachment = attachment;
  }
  public <T extends Attachment> T getAttachment(Class<T> type) {
    return type.cast(attachment);
  }
}

class FooApiMyObjectAttachment implements MyObject.Attachment {
  Foo foo; // some data that one MyApi implementer `foo' wants to persist between calls, but that is neither needed nor desired on MyObject 
}

class BarApiMyObjectAttachment implements MyObject.Attachment {
  Bar bar; // some data that another MyApi implementer `bar' wants to persist between calls, but that is neither needed nor desired on MyObject
}

class FooApi implements MyApi {
  // associates FooApiMyObjectAttachment with any MyObjects passed to it or created by it
}

class BarApi implements MyApi {
  // associates BarApiMyObjectAttachment with any MyObjects passed to it or created by it
}
```

Compared to subclassing, the advantage is that no factories are needed for `MyObject`, just so that implementers of `MyApi` can associate extra data with the objects.

Compared to a `WeakHashMap` in the implementers, a disadvantage is two methods on `MyObject` that aren't useful to clients, but an advantage is the simplicity.

A nice property of this pattern is that you can generalize it to store any number of attachments of different types with each node by changing the field to `Map<Class<?>, Attachment> attachments`, which cannot be done with subclassing at all.

I've seen the generalized form used successfully to annotate tree nodes in a tree rewriting system with various data used by various modules that processed the nodes. (c.f. pointers to parent nodes, origin information)

**Question**

Does this pattern have a name? If so, what is it? Any references?

Comment: The description is a little abstract for me to follow, but depending on how the interface is defined and what its semantics are, this looks very similar to Strategy or an inside-out Decorator.

Comment: Let's say that MyApi is a storage layer for example, that needs to remember some things between fetching an object and saving it. Or MyApi could be the API for a presentation component, that wants to store width and height and cache bitmaps for each object. Those are the cases I'm thinking about.

Comment: I'd say it's clearly a separate pattern from Strategy. I like Inside-Out Decorator though :-)

Comment: In related news, Google's real-time indexing is getting a bit scary. I thought that maybe something like "Attachment pattern" might work for this general idea... and this question came up as the second Google search result.

Comment: Found this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9472030/design-pattern-to-enhance-an-existing-data-structure-in-java-with-additional-inf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it!

The form where multiple attachments are possible (`Map<Class<?>, Attachment> attachments`) is described by Erich Gamma as the [Extension Objects Pattern](http://lcs3.syr.edu/faculty/fawcett/handouts/cse776/PatternPDFs/ExtensionObject.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a structural pattern, very close derivation from Whole-part, or composite.

Looking for a reference online, an overview of Whole-Part:

Sometimes called Composite

Helps with the aggregation of components (parts) that together form a semantic unit (whole).

Direct access to the Parts is not possible

Compose objects into tree structures to represent part-whole hierarchies.
Whole-Part lets clients treat individual objects and compositions of object uniformly

[Composite Pattern](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/composite)

Really the difference between what you are doing and the composite is that you are storing non-composites, so you don't get the tree structure that composites would allow, but a UML would look similar just without the pigs ear.

Comment: The tree structure is the very *essence* of Composite, and this really doesn't look much like it.

Comment: Yes, that is why a derivation.  It is still holding to the other principals of the composite.  Privacy and arbitrary component storage.    Also there could be a tree structure, there is no limitation on the structure given above.  It is the equivalent of a composite of Object type.

Comment: An important difference with the Composite pattern is that in Composite the behavior of the Component is influenced/extended by the Composites, whereas in Attachment (let's just call it that for now), there explicitly is no interaction between the "Component" and the "Composite": the composite is there only to store data in the component that is temporally coupled to the component, but functionally coupled to the interface (`MyApi `). In other words, `MyObject.Attachment` is an empty interface, a type bound only. The attachment could really be of type `Object` and it would be the same pattern.

Comment: I updated the code sample slightly to reflect this better (and added missing type bound on `getAttachment`..)

Answer (score 0):

The Gang of Four calls this a *Memento*.

Comment: Ooh, that's an interesting thought. The intent of Memento and what I'm doing here seem to be different though: Memento captures state so that you can reset an object back to a different (earlier) state, whereas Attachment stores extra state in an attachment, that the object itself doesn't need. That is, the attachment is state for a module that uses the object, that is coupled to the lifetime of the object.

So an important difference is that Memento captures the state of the object itself, whereas Attachment just adds extra state.

Answer (score 0):

The [Role Object Pattern](http://hillside.net/plop/plop97/Proceedings/riehle.pdf) is really really similar, maybe even up to the point where I conclude that the answer to my own question is: **It's the Role Object Pattern**.

Comment: Obviously 15 minutes after I post this I find the Extension Object Pattern... created another answer for that.